How can I only return an optional type if an input parameter is optional?
Is there a way I can use the magic of generics to write a function that returns an optional if the input is optional, otherwise both non-null?
For example, I have two functions that I want to combine into one.
static Timestamp dateToTimestamp(DateTime dateTime) {
  return Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime);
}

static Timestamp? dateToTimestampOptional(DateTime? dateTime) {
  return (dateTime == null) ? null : Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime);
}


I don't think that's practical, since the code for the combined version has to check for nulls and be null aware as if it were just the nullable version. You could make the null safe version as a wrapper that calls the nullable version, but you would no longer have null safe code for that case.

Make the type as generic
  Timestamp? dateToTimestamp<T extends DateTime?>(T dateTime) {
     return (dateTime == null) ? null : Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime); 
  }

